# Помогите понять суть задачи

Tags: c++, структуры-данных

Условие задачи звучит так:

> Реализовать работу с векторами и матрицами, представленными в виде разреженных списков. Реализовать операции сложения, умножения на скаляр, умножение матрицы на вектор, умножение матриц, транспонирования матриц.

Что такое разреженный список и что нужно знать для реализации данной задачи?
Буду писать на с++

Comment: Разреженные структуры данных - это структуры, которые хранят только действительные данные. Если заведена логическая матрица 1000х1000, то физически в памяти не будет ничего, если она не заполнена. Если обратиться к элементу, который не заведен, то вернется значение по умолчанию. Для умножения на скаляр - можно не пробегать по всем ячейкам, а умножать только заведенные. Это конечно сложнее реализовать, но за счет этого экономится память и достигается повышение скорости работы. Больше по теме: https://wiki2.org/en/Sparse_array

Comment: Имеется в виду, что нужно не заводить двухмерный массив N*N для матрицы, а вместо этого сделать список ненулевых элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разреженные структуры данных - это структуры, которые хранят только действительные данные. Если заведена логическая матрица 1000х1000, то физически в памяти не будет ничего, если она не заполнена. Если обратиться к элементу, который не заведен, то вернется значение по умолчанию. Для умножения на скаляр - можно не пробегать по всем ячейкам, а умножать только заведенные. Это конечно сложнее реализовать, но за счет этого экономится память и достигается повышение скорости работы. Больше по теме: wiki2.org/en/Sparse_array

Имеется в виду, что нужно не заводить двухмерный массив N*N для матрицы, а вместо этого сделать список ненулевых элементов.